# Topics to be covered in a sound design video tutorial?

Tags: design, sound, tutorial

I am currently preparing a sound design video tutorial for cinema and games (in french) that would last around 5 hours. According to you, which subject should not be forgotten ? What would you expect from such a tutorial ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A sound design tutorial would be great! First, I would go over some basic audio theory, and review waves, frequencies, etc. Depending on the DAW you will be using, I would go over the Digital Signal Processing tips as well. Talk about some good sound design plugins, and which combinations of plugins work best for creating certain effects. You could include some discussion about noise shaping, LFOs, and filtering. Then I would move on to discussing how to make specific sounds/noises. What's a good way to make an explosion sound, a punch sound, laser, etc. Also add some information about manipulating recorded sounds, vs manipulating synthetic sounds (created in the DAW), and when to use which. Subtitles in English would be nice as well!

Good luck, and I'm looking forward to checking it out!

Comment: Thanks for your insight Jeremy ! Lot of good ideas in your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do a tutorial for sound design I would suggest sticking with in the box plug-ins / applications. Tell about theory and basic understanding of audio. Most important, tell the history of sound design - and why we do it both in a technical sense and why we choose to do it as a craft.

Since the tutorial is about the understanding of sound design, you should talk about how important recording and mic placement is since that is probably the most important and crucial in order to manipulate it to get the sound you want. Then cover the topics of basic pitch/time changes and shift. If working in Pro Tools, talk about Varifi as well. (Great Plug-in)